# Sorting one column from excel and dividing it's contents based on the same entry's with Powershell export/import-excel

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory

I'm am currently in the need of some assistance with this little project.
I exported all AD users with a extentionAttribute "ABC" to an excelfile with help of export-excel, i called this the Datafile.xlsx
This gives me perfect results but these users are devided different offices and i want to provide the list of users that corresponds only with that office sorted in tabs.

Now i can manually sort the users in Excel based on the same entry in the column Office but i'd like to do that right away from the export, beside the fact that's hundreads of users. I could export on basis of the Office but that would mean i'd have manually start and edit 50+ time for each office and i don't know each office by it's exact name

So my question is; Is it possible to loop trough every entry in the column Office and move/populate another excel tab with all the antries that are the same.

```
Example
    Username  Office
    Andy      EastUS
    Pepper    WestUS
    Rose      Europe
    Harper    EastUS
    Denise    Europe
```

The result i'd like to have is that Andy would get his own Tab in an excel file, Harper and Pepper would get their own tab in excel file and Denise and Rose would get their own tab.
(later i'd like to add a API connection to mail the corresponding offices those file, but this is step one :)
Note that it has to be done with Powershell, despite the fact that there are other ways about this.

This is what i got so far, needless to say it doesn't work

```
# Specify the path to your Excel file
$excelPath = 'C:\temp\DataFile.xlsx'
# Read the Excel data
$data = Import-Excel -Path $excelPath -WorksheetName 'WorksheetName'

# Sort the data by the "Office" column
$sortedData = $data | Sort-Object Office

# Create a new Excel workbook
$outputWorkbook = New-Object -TypeName OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage

# Iterate through each unique name and create a worksheet
 foreach ($name in $sortedData.Office | Get-Unique) {
 
 $filteredData = $sortedData | Where-Object { $_.Office -eq $name }
 $worksheet = $outputWorkbook.Workbook.Worksheets.Add($name)
 $worksheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection($filteredData, $true)
 $worksheet.Cells[$worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns()
 }

# Save the output workbook
$outputPath = 'C:\temp\DataFileSorted.xlsx'
$outputWorkbook.SaveAs($outputPath)
$outputWorkbook.Dispose()

Write-Host "Excel file with sorted tabs created at: $outputPath"`
```

Comment: Use `help Group-Object` to see what it can do. You can also go straight to the developer of ImportExcel at https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues

Answer (score 0):

Start by opening the Excel Package first and importing your main worksheet (**assuming the worksheet name is "MainWorksheet* for this example*):

```bash
$pkg = Open-ExcelPackage .\test.xlsx
$xlsx = Import-Excel -ExcelPackage $pkg -WorksheetName MainWorksheet
```

If we inspect `$xlsx` we get a table like the one shown in question:

```
Username Office
-------- ------
Andy     EastUS
Pepper   WestUS
Rose     Europe
Harper   EastUS
Denise   Europe
```

So, from here you can use `Group-Object` grouping by the `.Office` property and from there, you can export each group to their corresponding worksheet by targeting the package (`$pkg`):

```bash
$xlsx | Group-Object Office | ForEach-Object {
    $pkg = $_.Group | Export-Excel -ExcelPackage $pkg -WorksheetName $_.Name -PassThru
}

Close-ExcelPackage $pkg
```

Now from here we can inspect if it work enumerating the worksheet with `Get-ExcelSheetInfo`:

```bash
Get-ExcelSheetInfo .\test.xlsx | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Name -eq 'MainWorksheet') {
        # exclude the `MainWorksheet`,
        # we already know how that one looks
        return
    }

    '- Worksheet Name: {0}' -f $_.Name | Out-Host
    Import-Excel -Path $_.Path -WorksheetName $_.Name | Out-Host
}
```

And its output would be a worksheet per `.Office` :D

```
- Worksheet Name: EastUS

Username Office
-------- ------
Andy     EastUS
Harper   EastUS

- Worksheet Name: Europe

Username Office
-------- ------
Rose     Europe
Denise   Europe

- Worksheet Name: WestUS

Username Office
-------- ------
Pepper   WestUS
```